# Como selecionar elementos que tenham um id válido?

Tags: jquery

Como faço para selecionar elementos que tenham um id definido? Por exemplo, dentro da section abaixo tenho o seguinte:

```
<section>
    <div class="div"></div>
    <div id=""></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</section>
```

No caso acima, eu preciso pegar **apenas** a 3ª e a 5ª div que tem um id válido e não vazio. Como posso pegar isso no jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você pode usar o seguinte seletor: `[id][id!='']`

```js
var elems = $("[id][id!='']");
console.log(elems);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div class="div"></div>
    <div id=""></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Ótima resposta @TobiasMesquita, editei somente pra visualização do resultado ficar mais confortavél pra nós.

Comment: Funcionou certinho!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```js
var el = $('[id]:not([id=""])');

console.log(el.get());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div class="div"></div>
    <div id=""></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</section>
```